# The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect - Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am facing an issue with submitting the value to the controller in Spring MVC.

When I call the controller with `href` it gets submitted to the controller method, I have submitted the following way :

`href='CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack_Calendar?date=<%=formatedDate%>'`

but when I submitted the same through javascript I get this exception `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

this is how I submit through javascript :

```
function getCasePackCalendar(date) {
     viewName ="CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack_Calendar?date="+date+" ";
     global.forms[0].action = viewName;
     global.forms[0].method = "GET"
     global.forms[0].submit()
}
```

and this is my controller method :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack_Calendar", method = RequestMethod.GET)

        public ModelAndView  CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack_Calendar(@RequestParam("date") String date,HttpServletRequest request) {
            String[] data = new String[] {date};
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String UserName = "";
        if(session.getAttribute("CIMtrek_UserName")!=null)
         UserName = session.getAttribute("CIMtrek_UserName").toString();
        ViewContent vc = new ViewContent();
        String HTML = vc
        .getContent(
        "com/cim/xml/CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack_sql.xml",
        "com/cim/xsl/view.xsl", "1 and 10","1","","0",UserName,data,"");

        List<String> ls = new ArrayList<String>();
            ls.add(HTML);
            logger.info("Welcome CIMtrek_Visitors_By___Unipart_Div__Date__Host___Visitor!");
            Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        model.put("list", ls);
        model.put("iSPost", "N");

        logger.info("Welcome CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments_Case_Pack!");

        return new ModelAndView("view", model);

        }
```

this is how I have form

```
<form id="CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments">
                                               <input type="hidden" id="CIMtrek_selectedIDs" name="CIMtrek_selectedIDs" value="" />
                                               <input type="hidden" id="CIMtrek_xmlData" name="CIMtrek_xmlData" value="" />
                                               <input type="hidden" id="CIMtrek_formName" name="CIMtrek_formName" value="CIMtrek_Compliance_Daily_Shipments" />
                                             </form>
```

what could be the problem.

Please help me to find it.

Best Regards.

Comment: Please use some debug tool(for example chrome F12->Network tab, or Firefox Firebug to see the request formed from the browser) In this case you are putting form parameters into the  view name (even adding some odd space symbol in quotes after the parameters) in your client js - it does not seem to be right. I suggest you to make a separate controller method that processes your form, but anyway this requires a lot of reading. In this case your form is incorrectly serialized,

Comment: Make this as answer. I will mark it as accepted so that this will help others. The problem is we should not append any value when submitting the page through java script, we can append the parameter in link but not while submitting the page with javascript

Comment: It probably doesn't mater but you might want to remove the company specific info from your code here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use some debug tool(for example in Chrome use F12->Network tab, or use Firefox Firebug to see the request formed from the browser) In this case you are putting form parameters into the view name (even adding some strange space symbol in quotes after the parameters) in your client js - it does not seem to be right.

I suggest you to make a separate controller method that processes your form.

In this case your form is incorrectly serialized(actually the correct html form serialization/parameter passing is regulated by several RFC).